# Django template re-rendering

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

So I have a django DetailView that I can easily render by getting all the data that I need from `get_context_data` in my class based view. But the problem is that each time to render this template I would need to choose a date in this template, get the date somehow and then re-render that same template from the date picked.

[image: select option]

I've been googling how to make this happen, there are something I could maybe do with AJAX, but maybe there is something easier to try, because I have little to no experience with AJAX/JS stuff

```
class PlaceDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionCheckMixin, PlaceViewMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "places/place_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlaceDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        place = context.get("object")

        contract = Contract.objects.filter(pk=place.id).first()
        context["renter"] = User.objects.filter(pk=contract.renter_id).first()

        now = timezone.now()

        meters = MeterInstallation.objects.filter(places=place.id)
        context["active_meters"] = meters.filter(active_until__gte=now)
        context["old_meters"] = meters.filter(active_until__lt=now)

        context["services"] = ServiceTask.objects.filter(place=place)

        # Need to add more context values from more models, but the date has to be given, how?

        return context


place_detail_view = PlaceDetailView.as_view()
```

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="values" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="values-tab">
        {% if values %}
          <div class="table-responsive-sm">
            <table class="table small">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Values</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              {% for value in values %}
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                  <!-- todo add needed values (type, values from/to, diff, tariff, total_price) -->
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        {% else %}
          No values.
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

I would like to know is there an option to re-render this template when a date is being picked? Or maybe there is a better option to make this happen?:)

Comment: "# Need to add more context values from more models, but the date has to be given, how?": Please can you elaborate this part?

Comment: @DipenDadhaniya I know that detailview makes a render for a given model and is only making a GET request, but that's the question for me, is there a chance that I could send a POST request with a date entered in the template and then from that date make more queries to re-render that template. https://imgur.com/a/Gx89WtH